# Putting in associated char (from ASCII) into Object type list

Tags: java, list, casting

I am looking to put in the associated char (for example, if the integer is 97, I want to place a lower case 'a' into an ArrayList)

What I have been trying thus far:

```
char[] myChar = Character.toChars(integerArray.get(i));;
                System.out.println(myChar);
                puzzleObjRow.add(myChar);
```

when I print it it prints the char I want, but when I add it I just get the random numbers/symbols etc (that were just in the memory or whatnot)

Is there anyway to typecast this to just a single char? (and not an array?) or what is a possible solution

thanks for any help

Answer (score 2):

If I get you right, you can just assign the first element in the array to a char:

```
char c = myChar[0];
```

(answering the comment) You may also do:

```
char c = (char)integerArray.get(i);
```

Comment: ahh that worked!....do you mind filling me in on why you cant just do this from the start? (and instead have to do it as an array)?